# CAKEPHP database update and add new entries

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

let, I hava a  database with table `A`. User edit data of a `field` (let, `A.promocode`) of that table `A` using a form and the form also have option to add new input fields and input data to this to add new entries to that field(`A.promocode`) using a specific `userid`.

Now How can I update those edited `promocode` entries and also add new `promocode` entries to the table for a specific `userid`.

please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by first registering the edit and then adding the new items.

Firstly table "A" is a very terrible example ... in cakephp convention tables should always be named in plural. But anyway at the top of your controller you will have the

```
$uses = array("A"); <-- This is you model
```

Within your action I would do something like this.

```
//First register the update
$this->A->id = $id //$id you will have to somehow post it with form maybe some hidden field
$this->A->set("promocode", $_POST["promocode"]);
$this->A->save();
$this->A->id = null; 

//Then register the new entries
foreach($newEntries as $newEntry) {
    $this->A->set("promocode", $newEntry["value"]);
    $this->A->set("user_id", $userid);
    $this->A->save();
    $this->A->id = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but hope it will helped

here your current field
and few dynamic fields

for saving data use A->saveAll($this->data)

field with id will be edited
but field without id will be created

```
<!-- current value-->
<input type="" name="data[A][edited_id][id]" value="edited_id"/>
<input type="" name="data[A][edited_id][promocode]" value="edited value"/>
<input type="" name="data[A][edited_id][user_id]" value="here user id"/>

<!-- new values-->
<input type="" name="data[A][1][promocode]" value="new value 1"/>
<input type="" name="data[A][1][user_id]" value="here user id"/>

<input type="" name="data[A][2][promocode]" value="new value 2"/>
<input type="" name="data[A][2][user_id]" value="here user id"/>

<input type="" name="data[A][3][promocode]" value="new value 3"/>
<input type="" name="data[A][3][user_id]" value="here user id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to save things in the db, here is a little example

```
//set some data (important, don't set the 'id')
$this->data['Workout']['user_id'] = $user_id;
$this->data['Workout']['name'] = "Ab Blaster"; 

//create workout then save it
$this->Workout->create();
$this->Workout->save($this->data);
```